# java.lang.VerifyError for AIDL Service

Tags: android, service, aidl, verifyerror, csip-simple

I'm working on getting an app communicating with an external service in another application (called CSipSimple). I'm able to bind to the service:

```
ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection(){
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName comp, IBinder svc){
        ISipService mSvc = ISipService.Stub.asInterface(svc); // Exception here
        ...
    }
    ...
}

Intent i = new Intent("com.csipsimple.service.SipService");
getApplicationContext().bindService(i, mConnection, BIND_IMPORTANT)
```

The exception is thrown on the indicated line. I've searched around and tried all of the following, to no avail:

- Adding the AIDL files to the source folder of the project
- Adding the other application (CSipSimple) as a required project
- Check off all of the entries in the Order/Export list
- Cleaning and rebuilding both applications

The following errors are generated:

```
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4276: Lcom/csipsimple/api/SipCallSession;.writeToParcel (Landroid/os/Parcel;I)V
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Lcom/csipsimple/api/SipCallSession;)
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY: [Ljava/lang/Object; is not instance of [Landroid/os/Parcelable;
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY: bad arg 1 (into [Landroid/os/Parcelable;)
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY:  rejecting call to Landroid/os/Parcel;.writeTypedArray ([Landroid/os/Parcelable;I)V
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x01dc
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): VFY:  rejected Lcom/csipsimple/api/ISipService$Stub;.onTransact (ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): Verifier rejected class Lcom/csipsimple/api/ISipService$Stub;
06-04 12:01:25.320: W/dalvikvm(8631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4191d930)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631): java.lang.VerifyError: com/csipsimple/api/ISipService$Stub
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at com.example.sipgather.MainActivity$1.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:37)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1101)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1118)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 12:01:25.328: E/AndroidRuntime(8631):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It looks like it can't find some of the required classes/methods, but I've added all of the AIDL files to my project. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like `ISipService.Stub.onTransact(Parcel, Parcel, int)` is passing an `Object[]` into `Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcelable[])`.  Missing methods and classes generally result in runtime failures ("no such method") rather than immediate verification failures, so the first couple of failure messages likely aren't fatal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by making `SipHome` a library, and including it in my application from the `Project Properties -> Android -> Library` dialog.